# Highlight selected item with Angular2 and RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, angular2-observables

I'm rewriting a simple Angular2 view component to using Observables and the async pipe. It shows a list of results and there is a selected result which should be highlighted.

Before my component had the following properties:

```
results: Result[] = [];
selectedResult: Result = null;
```

And the loop in the view looked something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let r of results" [class.active]="r === selectedResult" />
```

Now I have the following view component with observables:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'results-view',
    templateUrl: 'results-view.component.html'
})
export class ResultsViewComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private resultService: ResultService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    results: Observable<Result[]> = null;
    selectedResult: Observable<Result> = null;

    private selectRequests = new Subject<string>();

    ngOnInit(): void {
        let deviceId = this.route.snapshot.params['deviceId']

        this.results = this.resultService.getResults(deviceId);
        this.selectedResult = Observable.combineLatest(this.selectRequests.asObservable(), this.results, (sr, res) => {
            return res.filter(r => r.resultId == sr)[0];
        });      
    }

    selectResult(resultId: string): void {
        this.selectRequests.next(resultId);
    }
}
```

And the following view:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Alert</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let r of (results | async)" [class.active]="r === selectedResult">
            <td>{{r.Name}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="selectResult(r.resultId)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is not working. I also tried the angular expression

```
"r === (selectedResult | async)"
```

but it is not working either. The only thing that happened is that the `getResults` method was executed multiple times against the server.

What is the correct way of doing selection handling with observables?

Comment: `(selectedResult | async)` should be fine, note that with `===` you're comparing object references but these should be the same so try just printing the result of `async` with `{{ selectedResult | async }}` and see what it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it works now:

In the view I'm not comparing object references anymore but the object's ids (strings). So the loop in the view looks like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let r of (results | async)" [class.active]="r?.resultId == (selectedResult | async)?.resultId">
```

This left me with the problem that for every row a new subscription is created which in turn caused a `getResult()` back to the server.

My first attempt was to modify my observable like this:

```
this.results = this.resultService.getResults(deviceId).share();
```

Funnily this still left me with two calls back to the server (why???). But this one seems to work fine:

```
this.results = this.resultService.getResults(deviceId).publishLast().refCount();
```

This solution was inspired by [this](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html) blog post.

Answer (score 0):

for the same result you can use Attribute directives. Here is the link which will help you. 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#bindings

just catch the OnClick event not the OnMouseEnter() event.